# Why do Blogs created on Blogger show as 'Not Secure' even when Blogger is a Google Service?

Tags: google-workspace, google-chrome, blogger, blog

I recently created a blog on Blogger and even though it is a service offered by Google, Google Chrome shows the Blog as 'Not Secure'. What is the reason? How do I make sure that people are not afraid to access the Blog due to this? How do I convince Google it is secure?

- I am using the default site URL - [name].blogspot.com
- I am not using any 3rd party themes and/or gadgets.
- My blog does not include custom code or any such input.
- he blog is purely text by all means.
- It was created on 26th January 2021.

I tried to enable the HTTPS redirect from what I read on [this Google Support  post](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6284029?hl=en), but this did not make a difference (at least immediately). I visited the site the next day and it was marked as 'connection secure'.

Before I read the link above, I tried to do many different Google searches, but none of them worked out.

Comment: Are you connecting over TLS? Does the url start with **https://**?

Comment: @BillHorvath, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to make sure that your blogs are listed as 'secure' are that you must enable what is known as a 'HTTPS redirect' in your blog settings.

To access this setting, go to -> settings -> HTTPS and then enable an option called 'HTTPS redirect' if not already enabled.

[image: HTTPS redirect: Ensure that visits to HTTP redirect to HTTPS]

Though the site will take time to be listed as 'secure', the patience is totally worth it as people will trust you and your blog if Google vouches for it.